# Проблема с js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите найти ошибку.
При написании ничего не выводит.
файл правильно подключил (проверял `var ttt =10;alert(ttt)` было все нормально)
а после этого ничего не выводит

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var textH1 = $('#main_h1').text();
alert(textH1);
});
```

Comment: Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.  
Создайте пример вашей проблемы на jsfiddle.net, очевидно в приведенном коде ошибки нет.  
Не забывайте принимать ответы. У вас 0% принятых ответов.

Comment: Почему то у меня все равно не выходит

Comment: А что мне можно сделать,если оборачивается в подобную функцию

Answer (score 1):

Перепроверьте подключение библиотеки, ибо ваш пример рабочий - http://jsfiddle.net/y4N5Y/

Comment: <script src="js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript">,тут все правильно,а к примеру если выводить простую переменную,все нормально

Comment: type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- Общий div для всей в -->
  <div class="maindiv" id="main_div">
   <!-- Блок хедера (шапка сайта) -->
   <div id="forheader">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="900" height="108" alt="Хедер" title="Шапка сайта" />
   </div>
   <!-- Конец блока хедера -->
   <div id="forbody">
    <h1 id="main_h1">Добро пожаловать на сайт компании MotoRent!</h1>
код HTML

$(document).ready(function() {
var textH1 = ('#main_h1').text();
alert(textH1);
}); js

Comment: У вас знак доллара был пропущен.

    var textH1 = $('#main_h1').text();

Comment: Все равно не выходит

Comment: @ААА, все работает: http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/VKq2p/

Comment: а это почему пропустили $(document).ready(function()

Comment: @ААА, потому что по умолчанию оборачивается в подобную функцию.